# learning python regex and webscraping and stuck

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am trying to do web scraping using python.
I am trying to get the link for the product which is (my goal)

```
http://www.fastfurnishings.com/3-Piece-Reversible-Bonded-Leather-Match-Sofa-Set-i-p/bstrblm3p.htm
```

I am scraping this url / site

```
 http://www.fastfurnishings.com/SearchResults.asp?Search=3-Piece+Reversible+Bonded+Leather+Match+Sofa+Set+in+Cream
```

if you do a page view you will see that there is no certain ids or tags that can help me to pin point to the url that I need and I am not really good with regex as well. I have this so far in python

```
import urllib
import re
product = "3-Piece Reversible Bonded Leather Match Sofa Set in Cream"
productSearchUrl = product.replace(" ","+");
myurl = "http://www.fastfurnishings.com/SearchResults.asp?Search="+productSearchUrl
print myurl
htmlfile = urllib.urlopen(myurl)
htmltext = htmlfile.read()
regex = '<td valign="top" width="33%" align="center">(.+?)</td> '
r = re.compile(regex)
print re.findall(r,htmltext)
```

but thats not reading anything...any help will be appreciated

Comment: Please see the answer with 4000 votes to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: Use `re.DOTALL` to make the `.` match newlines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is why you use HTML Parsers such as [`BeautifulSoup`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/):

```
>>> import urllib2
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
>>> html = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.fastfurnishings.com/SearchResults.asp?Search=3-Piece+Reversible+Bonded+Leather+Match+Sofa+Set+in+Cream')
>>> soup = BS(html)
>>> print soup.find('td', {'valign':'top', 'width':'33%', 'align':'center'}).a['href']
http://www.fastfurnishings.com/3-Piece-Reversible-Bonded-Leather-Match-Sofa-Set-i-p/bstrblm3p.htm
```

See how easy that was ;)

Comment: you are sooooo awesome!

Comment: one quick question what if print soup.find('td', {'valign':'top', 'width':'33%', 'align':'center'}).a['href'] doesnt exist. It will then  throw an exception. How can I avoid that.

Comment: @Autolycus Replace the `['href']` with `.get('href')`. If a `href` doesn't exist, it will return `None`

Comment: this didnt work print soup.find('td', {'valign':'top', 'width':'33%', 'align':'center'}).get('href') what am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Autolycus You forgot the `.a`

Comment: @Autolycus So, altogether, the correct code is `print soup.find('td', {'valign':'top', 'width':'33%', 'align':'center'}).a.get('href')`

Comment: no go on that..this is my stacktrace Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "asimsScrapper.py", line 11, in <module>
    print soup.find('td', {'valign':'top', 'width':'33%', 'align':'center'}).a.get('href')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'a'

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37305/discussion-between-autolycus-and-haidro)

Answer (score 3):

You are better off using a web scraper library such as [Scrapy](http://scrapy.org/) or [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/). Will definitely save you a lot of pain and will make you focus on what you actually want to achieve after scraping the information.

Answer (score 0):

Dont do this, etc. Looks like there are newlines you're not accounting for:

```
r = re.compile(regex, re.DOTALL)
```